# Why is sequelize Intellisense not working?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, sequelize.js

How I can turn on Intellisense of node.js sequelize?

There is no model method:

[image: no intellisense for sequelize model]

What I can do?

Answer (score 17):

i solved the problem related to sequelize intellisense by changing my general require syntax to

```
 const {Sequelize}=require('sequelize');
```

Comment: I think this can cure intellisense on the `sequelize` instance, but it doesn't seem to (and shouldn't) make any difference on instances of `Model` subclasses.  Models are not derived from the `sequelize` instance

Answer (score 2):

What I found is that The previous versions of Intellisense is working, but not stable ( or 6.x) version.
So you can try this:

`const {Sequelize} = require("sequelize");`
or
`const Sequelize = require("sequelize").Sequelize`

Either of this following works.

Answer (score 1):

according to:

https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/11103

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize').Sequelize;
```

Answer (score 0):

follow this you will get Intellisense works properly.

1. /models/index.js

```
'use strict';
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

const db = {};


/**
 * @type {Sequelize.Sequelize}=con
 */
let con = new Sequelize(process.env.db_database, process.env.db_username, process.env.db_password, {
  host: process.env.db_host,
  dialect: "mysql"
});


(async function () {
  try {
    //ck connection
    await con.authenticate()
    //attach models
    db.User = require('./User')
    db.Test = require('./Test')

    //associate
    Object.keys(db).forEach(modelName => {
      // if (db[modelName].associate) {
      //   db[modelName].associate(db);
      // }
    });

    //sync
    await con.sync({
      logging: true,
      force: false
    })
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("error db con: ", e.name)
  }
}())


db.con = con
module.exports = db;
```

2. /models/User.js

```
const { DataTypes } = require('sequelize');
const { con } = require('.');

const User = con.define("User", {
    name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    password: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    }
})

module.exports = User
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an ES6 way to get IntelliSense working on your models (instead of just the instantiated class).

First - declare the sequelize instance which can be imported into many files.

```js
// sequelize.js

const { Sequelize } = require('sequelize');

const sequelize = new Sequelize(...);

export default sequelize;
```

Second - follow the suggested setup by sequelize-cli. Note you need to reimport the model. I know this might seem annoying to continually add `export` declarations here but when you add this 1 line, you get all the benefit :)

```js
// models/index.js
import Sequelize from 'sequelize';
import sequelize from '../config/sequelize';

export * from './user';
export * from './another-model';
// ... etc

let db = {};

const basename = path.basename(__filename);

fs.readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter((file) => file.indexOf('.') !== 0 && file !== basename && file.slice(-3) === '.js')
  .forEach((file) => {
    const module = require(path.join(__dirname, file));
    Object.values(module).forEach((model) => {
      db[model.name] = model;
    });
  });

Object.keys(db).forEach((modelName) => {
  if (db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});

export {
  sequelize,
  Sequelize,
  migrations
};
```

Third - update model file like so.
Note: adding `export` keyword here and importing your base sequelize instance.

```js
//models/MyModel.js
import Sequelize from 'sequelize';
import sequelize from '../sequelize';

const { DataTypes } = Sequelize;

export const User = sequelize.define('User', {
  userId: DataTypes.UUID,
  ...
}, {});

User.associate = function (models) {
  User.belongsTo(models.Admin, {
    foreignKey: 'adminId',
  });
};
```

Sharing this since I struggled to find a working example since if you follow the official docs, you don't get IntelliSense on the models.

[example showing models on db object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWQw2.png)
[example showing sequelize intellisense](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2qZ2.png)

Answer (score 0):

On your database configuration, when you import sequelize import it like

```
    const Sequelize = require("sequelize").Sequelize;
    const sequelize = new Sequelize("dbname", "dbuser", "password", {
     host: "host",
     dialect: "dialect",
   });
   module.exports = sequelize;
```

Answer (score -1):

The reason you are not getting the Intellisense might be because you are not `importing` your models through sequelize correctly. Assuming you are defining your models in separate files and then importing them. I would recommend doing the following:

1. Create an `index.js` file in your `models` folder
2. Use `sequelize.import` to import all your models and associate them as well.
3. Then export them all from index.js along with `seqeulize db instance` and `Sequelize` module.
4. Wherever in your project you need your models just `require` db from `/models`.

---

**models/index.js**

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize(DB_NAME, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD)
const db = {
    Sequelize: Sequelize,
    sequelize,
    User: sequelize.import("./user"),
    Message: sequelize.import("./message")
}

Object.keys(db).forEach(model => {
    if ("associate" in db[model]) {
        db[model].associate(db)
    }
})

module.exports = db
```

Comment: There are multiple ways of defining and importing Sequelize models including in their own documentation. Your quoted method is not the only 'correct' way. Additionally, this way  does not cure intellisense not working on model instances.